# Keeping nested pages persistent inside a flutter app

Tags: flutter, persistence

I am currently working on an app using the flutter framework I have the main.dart file loading the homefeed page with bottom navigation bar with two tabs one for home and one for settings... The home.dart file is loading the body.dart whereas the body.dart file is loading list.dart and the problem occurs when I go to the settings tab and go back to the home tab the home page gets rebuilt. how can I keep all pages persistent?

To give you a basic idea:

home.dart:

```
Scaffold(
....
body: Body();

...
);
```

body.dart:

```
Scaffold(
...
body: List();
...
);
```

Comment: Please include some code. It's hard to tell what exactly why your code is rebuilding without seeing how you're building things.

Comment: It's as basic as you can imagine The home.dart page is loading the body.dart page then the body.dart page is loading the list.dart page I just want to know how I can keep all these pages being loaded by home.dart to stay persistent?

Comment: Yes, I realize that is what you asked. What I'm saying is that there are many different ways to show pages and transition between them; how you did it has a direct relation on how to fix it. Without seeing some of your code, it's impossible to tell which case this and to give you advice on how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can store necessary tabs state in the Home widget. When building tabs, pass appropriate state through constructor. When user switch tab, the state will persist because it's stored inside root widget.

If you'll need to pass the state to number of nested levels, consider using some packages like scoped_model, flutter_bloc or flutter_redux

Comment: Even if it's a custom bottom navigation bar?

Comment: You can also register a GlobalKey is you want to store something and reference that as a static object. However, keep in mind it is recommended very rarely as it costs a lost of loading overhead.

Comment: @DeadPool yes, for custom too. Basic idea is if you want to keep tab's state, store it in root widget's state instead

Comment: What widgets or classes can I use to make them persistent?